# cannot get key name from angularfire orderByPriority

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm using v0.7.1 and already convert objects to array with this

```
<div ng-repeat="data in datas | orderByPriority">{{data.$id}}</div>
```

but nothing show. any idea?

**update**
include fiddler
http://plnkr.co/edit/KrktzaU7AzJIGKfW8w2k

Comment: You didn't provide enough info in order for us to help you... Does it print anything at all without the filter?

Comment: @AlexanderBurakevych updated the question.  yes, the data is print fine with and without filter. just `$id` not showing.  please check fiddle. tanks

Comment: @vzhen your fiddle doesn't take data from Firebase - it means that the object you are filtering is not angularFire instance, it doesn't have $getIndex property that's why $id is not added: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/blob/master/angularfire.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle doesn't receive data from Firebase - it means that the object you are filtering is not angularFire instance, so it cannot potentially know its $id ($getIndex).

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['firebase']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $firebase, $timeout) {
    $scope.datas = $firebase(new Firebase("https://jsfiddle001.firebaseio.com/"));
});
```

I modified your fiddle and it works fine:
http://plnkr.co/edit/zM1CFmEJJ4s3BIqBzmqG?p=preview

orberByPriority doesn't provide any extra options, e.g. to reverse order. Chain Angular filters to get more flexibility:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in datas | orderByPriority | orderBy : '$id' : true">
```

Comment: ahhhhhh   thank you so much.  I forgot to have the data in firebase and you make me clear because i thought the `$id` from pure firebase js. it actually from angularFire.

Comment: I missed something. How to reverse order in orderByPriority?

Comment: Well, you cannot. Try to use angular orderBy filter chained with orderByPriority. See updated answer.